# How can I use same navigation bar but different pages/FAB

Tags: flutter

I have multiple pages in my app but each page has its own floating action button with different functionality (tied to the page itself), each page is a scaffold essentially, what i want is to use the same bottom navigation bar in all of them but have only the body of the scaffold and the FAB change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question itself has an answer but still here is a way you can try

In pubsec.yaml

```
  bmnav: ^0.3.4
```

You can use bottom bar navigation like this

```
class BottomBarActivityState extends State<BottomBarActivity> {
  //different screens on selection of tabs
  final List<Widget> screens = [
    screen1(),
    screen2(),
    screen3(),
   ];
  Widget currentScreen = screen1();
  int currentTab = 0;
  final PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageStorage(child: currentScreen, bucket: bucket),
      bottomNavigationBar: bmnav.BottomNav(
        index: currentTab,
        items: [
          bmnav.BottomNavItem(Icons.home),
          bmnav.BottomNavItem(Icons.home),
          bmnav.BottomNavItem(Icons.home),
        ],
        onTap: (i) {
          setState(() {
            currentTab = i;
            currentScreen = screens[i];
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

## Edit

screen1

```
class screen1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  screen1State createState() {
    return new screen1State();
  }
}

class screen1State extends State<screen1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("screen1"),
      ),
      body: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        onPressed: _onPressd,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onPressd() {}
}
```

screen 2

```
class screen2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  screen1State createState() {
    return new screen2State();
  }
}

class screen2State extends State<screen2> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("screen1"),
      ),
      body: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        onPressed: _onPressd,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onPressd() {}
}
```

Comment: I've seen this solution but I have 2 problems with this. First of all this doesn't change my floating action button, and if i were to do the same approach for the FAB (Instead of just the body) then i face other problems with the onPressed() of the FAB and the setState etc (i tried). So essentially i want to get the scaffold and FAB from my other pages. Also how efficient is it to store all the pages in a list?

Comment: this is not a list this is a bottom navigation bar and for changing FAB you can take FABs on screen1(),screen2(),screen3() differently and define the onPressed on it

Comment: The problem is that the onPressed of each navigation bar first uses a lot of helper functiosn defined in the class, and 2 they have their own set state on the widget, when i tried using the different on pressed i had problems each onPressed of a FAB for a page uses setState (which i couldn't use in my main home page to set state of a diff page) and requires access to a few fields.

Comment: what you want is on clicking on fab you want to go to different page ?

Comment: why do you want this each onPressed of a FAB for a page uses setState (which i couldn't use in my main home page to set state of a diff page)

Comment: are you able to understand my answer or should I add more code so that it will be more precise to you and secondly as your questions states you have to use bottom navigation bar as there is no alternative to this as far as I know

Comment: No i do understand. I am doing a budget management app. My first page is the homepage, when i click on the FAB it will take me to the "add payment" page (so this is the FAB of the homepage). In the payments page (which btw can also be accessed from the bottom navigation bar) the FAB instead would "add a new payment" prompting a dialogue and so on. So my idea is that the FAB differs in its actions based on the page. And in some cases my FAB has a functionality that requires to invoke a setstate on the page (which i cant since there's one FAB in main page and i want to set state for diff page)

Comment: So yes i can achieve what u showed by binding each "page" widget to a bottom navigation bar item but my problem lies with the FAB as my "page" widget is essentially nothing but the body of the scaffold excluding the FAB whereas in my case i need both the body and FAB of the scaffold to differ based on the Bottom navigation bar item i select.

Comment: that is why I provided you this solution for using bottom navigation bar

Comment: I didn't know this bottom navigation bar works differently than what I've tried. This works perfectly thank you! I had a similar idea but diff implementation with material design's bottom navigation bar this is much better!

Comment: Thank god you understood.

Comment: why did you unaccepted my answer after accepting it

Answer (score 1):

```
int _currentIndex = 0;

enter code body

body:
  pages(_currentIndex),
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    onTap: onTabTapped,
    currentIndex: _currentIndex,
    items: [
     //Enter your Menu list here
    ],
  ),

code page

pages(int currentPosition) {
switch (currentPosition) {
  case 0:
    return new pagehome();
  case 1:
    return new pagesongs();
  ...
  default:
    return new Text("Error");
 }
}

click event

void onTabTapped(int index) {
setState(() {
  _currentIndex = index;
 });
}
```